# Good books on O.D.E the includes analysis of singularities

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, stability-in-odes

What are some good reference books on O.D.E the include analysis of singularities?

Comment: This is totally ludicrous .  I asked for a reference and people put it on hold because its off-topic. Abusing the power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Arnold's Ordinary Differential Equations* is a great book on the subject, and does cover the topic of singular points.